# C# Custom DateTime to Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I'm trying to do a custom conversion.  I have a DateTime object from a C# WebAPI call coming to me as a string in the Format "03/17/2006"

C#

```
pastDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).
```

JS

```
var date = new Date(result.date);
var options = {year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" }
            $j('#pastDate').text(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options));
```

This is changing my "03/17/2006" date string from the API call to this:
"March 16, 2006, 11:00:00 PM"

However, what I'm looking for is: "March 17, 2006".

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need to also display as localized? (MM/DD/YYYY, vs other orderings and separators)

Comment: basically its a time zone issue. as user3573206 mentions in his answer, use moment.js

Comment: StingyJack - No, US only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(result.date))
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately.  I might have to try out integrating moment.js as was suggested before.